# @Background is being executed in UI main Thread for EFragment

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-annotations

In Android-Annotations, @Background is not creating a separate thread. Instead this code is being run in main UI Thread. I come to this conclusion, on the basis of following code :-

```
@Background
void doGetMoreDishesWishedList() {
    Log.d(TAG, "doGetMoreDishesWishedList");
    Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(android.os.Process.myTid()));
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
        Log.d(TAG, "In main loop");
    else
        Log.d(TAG, "Not In main loop");
}

@UiThread
void updateUiGetMoreDishesWishedList(long requestSentTime, ArrayList<UserDishContainer> newList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUiGetMoreDishesWishedList");
    Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(android.os.Process.myTid()));
}
```

Result is :-

```
04-07 21:11:33.359: D/WishlistFragment(26346): doGetMoreDishesWishedList
04-07 21:11:33.359: D/WishlistFragment(26346): 26346
04-07 21:11:33.359: D/WishlistFragment(26346): In main loop
04-07 21:11:34.372: D/WishlistFragment(26346): updateUiGetMoreDishesWishedList
04-07 21:11:34.372: D/WishlistFragment(26346): 26346
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Selvin I am printing Thread Id not Process Id

Comment: so why don't you use java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getID()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here :

1. Could you tell us how you're launching this test activity ? I suspect that you're using the original activity instead of the generated one.
2. As @selvin said, you should use `Thread.currentThread()` to get the current thread. And to check if it's the main thread, use this snippet : `Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()`.